# Clustered HTTP sessions using Hazelcast in jhipster generator

Tags: jhipster

Which options to pick during application generation for being able to pick the option:

```
Clustered HTTP sessions using Hazelcast
```

This option is mentioned in the documentation https://www.jhipster.tech/creating-an-app/#2
But somehow I am not able to pick it. Is is automatically selected when I choose hazelcast as cache provider?

Is there an equivalent yo-rc.json setting?

Comment: 1. Yes, 2. No Why don't you try? See https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/blob/main/generators/server/templates/src/main/java/package/config/CacheConfiguration.java.ejs

Comment: So http session clustering ist automatically added? I tried mate, I generated lots of jhipster apps today.

Comment: Not fully, you must add Spring Session but as the Hazelcast cluster is already built based on which service discovery you selected, it's no that hard.

Comment: The option must have been removed at some point from JHipster due to extremely low interest from users. It must have flown under the radar as I don't find any issue or pr about it since 2017.

Comment: Hmm too bad. But thank your for the information. Do you know if there is another recommended way to share http sessions between instances?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It has [been removed with this PR](https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/pull/6944) following a public vote on our [mailing list](https://groups.google.com/forum/?utm_medium=email&utm_source=footer#!topic/jhipster-dev/A6HabUyZRRY). So obviously the documentation has not been updated.